# angular array item not updating on scope change

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Spent a few hours on this already, sifted through numerous stack posts and blogs but can't seem to get this to make my model update. More specifically, I am trying to update an array item (ng-repeat). In the simple case below, I iterate over venues list, and upon toggling a "like" button, I update the server appropriately, and reflect the change on the venues item on the $scope.

in my *search.html* I have a directive:

```
<ion-content>
   <venues-list venues="venues"></venues-list>
</ion-content>
```

and search controller I have:

```
app.controller('bleh', function(Service) {
   ...
   $scope.venues = [{ id: 1, name: 'Venue1', like: false },{ id: 2, name: 'Venue2', like: false }];
   ...
});
```

Nothing unusual there. Then in my venues-list directive:

```
app.directive('venues-list', function() {

   function venueListController($scope, Service) {

      $scope.likeToggle = function(venue, $index) {
            Service.likeVenue(venue.id, !venue.like).then(function() {
               $scope.venues[$index].like= !venue.like;
            });
      }
   }

   return {
      strict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'venue.html',
      controller: venueListController,
      scope: {
         venues: '='
      }
   }
});
```

then in my *venue.html* I have:

```
<div ng-repeat="venue in venues">
  <p>{{venue.name}}</p>
  <button ng-click="likeToggle(venue, $index)">Like</button>
</div>
```

I have tried many different options:

```
$scope.$apply() // after updating the $scope or updating scope within apply's callback function;
$scope.$digest()
$timeout(function() { // $scope.venues[$index] .... }, 0);
safe(s,f){(s.$$phase||s.$root.$$phase)?f():s.$apply(f);}
```

so

```
safe($scope, function() { $scope.venues[$index].like = !venue.like });
```

I haven't yet used the link within the directive, but my venues.html template is obviously a little more elaborate than presented here.

**EDIT:**

Just to keep the discussion relevant, perhaps I should have mentioned - the data is coming back from the server with no issues, I am handling errors and I am definitely hitting the portion of the code where the $scope is to be updated. NOTE: the above code is a small representation of the full app, but all the fundamental pieces are articulated above.

1. Search Controller
2. Venues Service
3. venue-list directive and venue.html template to accompany the directive
4. directive controller

**EDIT #2**

```
$scope.foo = function() {
   $scope.venues[0].like = !$scope.venues[0].like;
}
```

Just to keep it even simpler, the above doesn't work - so really, the bottom line is my items within an array are not reflecting the updates ...

**EDIT #3**

```
$scope.foo = function() {
   $scope.venues[0].like = !$scope.venues[0].like;
}
```

My apologies - just to re-iterate what I was trying to say above - the above is changing the scope, however, the changes are not being reflected on the view.

Comment: Did you try 'orderBy' on venue.like? there is no need to start a $digest circle, you have attched venues to $scope.

Comment: also can you post a fiddle?

Comment: `app.module('bleh', function(Service) {` module? is it `controller`?

Comment: vp_arth: sorry my bad, yes controller - I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: Itsik: I'll try and find time to do a quick fiddle. I tried without kicking off a $digest cycle - from what I understand ng-click does this internally (stand to be corrected). ... even an expression i.e. <div>{{venue.like}}</div> always stays the same state even after attempting to toggle and update form controller.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the issue is with your service and promise resolution.. Can you put a console.log there and see if the promise resolution is working fine? or Can you share that code bit. Also where are you checking for scope update? within directive or outside

Comment: Agreed.  Looking at the code, I see you don't have an error handler put in place for the service call.  If you are encountering an error there, you're never going to see it, and that could account for the bug you're seeing.

Comment: insanevirus: service calls are working as expected and returning a successful update of the DB ... so I am definitely hitting $scope.venues[$index].like= !venue.like; ... like I said, everything in the app works fine apart from the update of individual items.... even if i refresh (and re-fetch from the server), it will reflect the change appropriately ... but obviously I don't want to be hitting the server, every time I hit a "like" button :)

Comment: Maurice Reeves: I'm handling errors on my app, as I mentioned, this is just a slightly simplified representation. only included relevant bits

Comment: @Sash service call may be working fine. But after the success response is received, the promise resolution might be having issues. In which case then will not get called ever. So just put an alert or comment inside **then** there to ensure that it is getting called indeed

Comment: ohh ok. The scope is not getting updated inside/outside directive or both places ?

Comment: insanevirus: just did it now... it's hitting as expected. p.s. I was getting errors previously when tried $apply and $digest that $digest cycle was already running.

Comment: insanevirus: scope is not getting updated inside the directive controller. (take a look at venues-list directive and venues.html template up above)

Comment: lol I just realized i'm not doing the @ <name> :) to address each one of you appropriately

Comment: @Sash no problem. But again you are saying service is hitting as expected but is **then** getting called is what I'm asking you to check. Sorry to be persistent but sometimes it's all silly issues! :)

Comment: @insanevirus *then* is getting called yes.

Comment: Ok. I doubt then it's an angular issue. Is there a possibility you are updating the like variable twice somewhere in your code accidentally. Causing it to toggle back to original value?. This dummy code looks fine but as you said your original code is a bit more complex

Comment: @Sash while you have found a way around for now, the real issue still remains unclear. Nothing seemed wrong in terms of angular.. Also, If you get some free time please make a plunkr, so we can try to resolve the original as well :)

Answer (score 1):

OK after some refactoring I finally got it working.

The "fix" (if you want to call it that) to my specific problem was:

instead of passing an array of venues, I was iterating over the array on the parent controller, passing in a venue as an element attribute that would bind (two-way) on the isolated scope of the directive.

so, instead of:

```
<ion-content>
   <venues-list venues="venues"></venues-list>
</ion-content>
```

I now have:

```
<ion-content>
   <venues-list ng-repeat="venue in venues" venue="venue"></venues-list>
</ion-content>
```

and my directive now looks like:

```
app.directive('venues-list', function() {

   function venueController($scope, Service) {

      $scope.likeToggle = function(venue) {
            Service.likeVenue(venue.id, !venue.like).then(function() {
               $scope.venue.like = !venue.like;
            });
      }
   }

   return {
      strict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'venue.html',
      controller: venueController,
      scope: {
         venue: '='
      }
   }
});
```

This did the trick!